# naive Bayes probability formula

Tags: naivebayes

In this photo is the probability with the Naives Bayes algorithm of :Fem:dv/m/s Young own Ex-credpaid Good ->62% and I calculated the Probability so: P(Fem:dv/m/s | Good)*P(Young | Good)*P(own | Good)*P(Ex-credpaid | good)*P(Good) -> 1/6*2/6*5/6*3/6*0.6=0,01389 and I dont Know where I Failed, could someone please tell me where is my error?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIinW.jpg)

Comment: In Naive Bayes each conditional probability (e.g. `P(own|Good)`) is assumed to follow some probability distribution, for example Normal distribution or Bernoulli distribution, however you're trying to compute it directly from the dataset. You should provide more context if you want some help. Also, you're question is not appropriate for stackoverflow because it's not about programming, it's only about math

Comment: @user322778 what I want to do is the algorithm "Classifying without Discriminating" and these table was in a Example, where explain the algorithm, and these said, that you need first a ranker for classification the dataset(the dataset is the Table), and the ranker will it do with Naive Bayes classifier , not more.